# Which Linux package contains the 'top' command?

Tags: linux, centos, top

Many of the common utilities in Linux either come packaged in util-linux from [Linux Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Foundation) or [coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) from GNU. The man page for [top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29) doesn't specify anything.

I am using CentOS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "top" utility is in the "procps" package on RHEL/CentOS systems.

Answer (score 16):

You can do `yum whatprovides <path>` to see what package provides a file.  For example, `yum whatprovides /usr/bin/top` will tell you for top or `yum whatprovides '*/top'` if you weren't sure of the path.

Comment: How is that going to work if he doesn't have it installed? It's in procps.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy: Who doesn't have `procps` installed. Anyway, `yum whatprovides '*/top'` also works if you don't know the path, as said.

Comment: I'm not sure what having it installed has to do with it, you can still find out what package provides a file with that command, even if the file doesn't exist on your disk.  It's how you would lookup what to install to get a file

Comment: The last command need quoting or escaping to work reliably. Could be written as `yum whatprovides "*/top"`, `yum whatprovides '*'/top`, `yum whatprovides \*/top`, or some other variation of it.

Comment: I know this question was tagged [centos] but just for reference: Pacman: `pkgfile /usr/bin/top`; Apt: `apt-file search /usr/bin/top`.

Comment: this is rpm basic usage question "rpm -qf $(which top)"